# Rotate a graphic by user input (animation)

Tags: java, animation, rotation

I'm trying to write a program that simulates forces and I'm stuck on a section where I need to rotate the graphic by the angle the user inputs.

Here the code for the graphic so far.

```
private class MomentsAnimation extends JPanel {

    int width = 440;
    int height = 300;

    int rotationAngle = 60;

    public MomentsAnimation() {
        setSize(width, height);
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        int xcentre = width / 2;
        int ycentre = height / 2;

        g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(xcentre - 5, ycentre - 5, 10, 10); // draw the point of rotation, does not move in the animation

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillArc(xcentre - 150, ycentre - 50, 100, 100, 0, 45);

        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawLine(xcentre - 100, ycentre, xcentre, ycentre - 100); // draws the diagonal force line 

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawLine(xcentre - 100, ycentre, xcentre, ycentre); // draws horizontal line of distance from point of rotation

        g.drawString("θ", xcentre - 70, ycentre - 10);

    }


}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the rotating part of your question. You can cast your Graphics object to a Graphics2D object which has a rotate method.

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
```

Then you can rotate what you are going to draw by calling:

```
g2.rotate(radians);
```

Be aware that the rotation is to be given in radians and not in degrees. But you can use the math class to convert between degrees and radians like so:

```
double rad = Math.toRadians(degrees);
```

As for the user input there is any number of different ways to obtain that. You could use JOptionPane for a GUI style input or you can use the Scanner class to read the rotation from the command line. After that you can store the given rotation as a variable somewhere in your code and use it in your paint method.

I hope this helps :)